# For which values of a does the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{j})^a}{j}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which values of a does the series
$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\bigl(\tfrac{1}{j}\bigr)^a}{j}$
 converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use *equivalence*: $\;\sin u\sim_0 u$, so
$$ \frac{\sin\bigl(\tfrac{1}{j}\bigr)^a}{j}\sim_{j\to\infty}\frac1{j^{a+1}}.$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: could you explain why they are equal, I want some details

Comment: The general terms of each series? They're not equal, they're only (asymptotically) equivalent, which means their ratio tends to $1$ at infinity. Furthermore, we know that two series with *positive* equivalent terms both converge or both diverge. Is it clearer?